# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest causing server error

Tags: powershell

I have an xml file and I'm using a Powershell script to create a soap request to post it to the url.

The problem I seem to have is with this line of code below producing a server error:

```
[xml]$res = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method POST -ContentType "text/soap+xml;charset=windows-1252" -Body $soapReq
```

The odd thing is when I open my data XML file in notepad and save it (make no changes), the Powershell script seems to work and transfer the file across to the target url.

I'm writing my xml file in UTF8 charset.

I enclose a tweaked version of Powershell script I am using.

```
#my db generates this file
$filePath = "C:\MyPath\data.xml"

$result = Get-Content $filePath

#rewrite the file to a specific location and encode it to utf-8
Out-File -FilePath $filePath -InputObject $result -Encoding 'UTF8'

$un = 'un'
$Pw = 'pw'

$xmlData = Get-Content $filePath -Raw
$xmlData = [Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($xmlData)

$soapReq = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins0="https://url">
<env:Body>
  <ins0:Transfer>
    <sourceIdentifier>123456</sourceIdentifier>
    <userName>$un</userName>
    <password>$pw</password>
    <xmlDataset>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
$xmlData</xmlDataset>
  </ins0:Transfer>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
"@

$uri = "https://url"

[xml]$res = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method POST -ContentType "text/soap+xml;charset=windows-1252" -Body $soapReq
```

Before I investigate using vbs to open the file in notepad and save it (overkill), I’m hoping someone can give me advice on how to get this Powershell script working properly.

Comment: Can you post your full code and redact or change any private information?

Comment: _"producing a server error"_  Can you post the full error message?

Comment: `windows-1252` code page is not associated with UTF8 encoding, correct? Isn't that ASCII?

Comment: @AdminOfThings ANSI (one of the many ANSI encodings to be precise).

Comment: Added full PS script, and changed very little. Hopefully someone can identify the cause.

Comment: If `xmlDataset` really needs to contain an entire escaped (quoted) XML document, it's probably easier to just stick that in a `<![CDATA[...]]>` section. Even then I sincerely doubt the XML directive is necessary or wanted -- for starters, you really cannot have an UTF-8 encoded document inside what is declared to be a Windows-1252 encoded document, even if it "works" if you just stick to ASCII characters; I'd recommend making the whole request UTF-8.

Comment: I've changed both the encoded windows-1252 lines to UTF-8 now and tried the script with an escaped version of my data.xml as well as the normal version of my data.xml in the <![CDATA[]]> . Still fails. I think it's got to be my data.xml file.